# CSS Bootstrap input-group-text border

Tags: html, css, focus, bootstrap-5

I have an input group with icon placed before the input. I would lika to change the border of the whole input-group when the input is focused + change the color of the fa-icon

HMTL

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">
        <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'search']" size="1x"></fa-icon>
      </span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.input-group-text{
  background-color: white;
  color: var(--gray-200);
}

.form-control{
  height: 50px;
  border-left: 0;
}

.form-control:focus{
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
  border-left: 0;
}

.form-control:focus + .input-group-text{
  border: 1px solid var(--primary-color);
}
.form-control:focus + fa-icon{
  color: var(--primary-color);
 }
```

I tried multiple variations of the selector above but i am still unable to change this to the wanted state. I am using bootstrap 5 in angular.